# video HTML5 tag didn't work in IE

Tags: html

I have the following html5 code that display video:

```html
<section class="video">
  <h2>Video from last year</h2>
  <video src="http://ak.channel9.msdn.com/ch9/265b/9a76fccd-941e-4285-ad00-9ea200aa265b/MIX09KEY01_high_ch9.mp4"></video>
  <div class="video-controls" style="display: none">
    <button class="video-play">Play</button>
    <button class="video-pause">Pause</button>
    <span class="video-time"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried it in many pc's with the same spec it worked in all but only in one pc didn't show up. Why?

Comment: You are claiming `video didn't work in IE` and you have tried the code in several `pc's`. Where all the pc's running window IE?

Comment: There may be a lot of things that caused the video didn't work.

Comment: Yes, they're all running with windows IE with the same version

Comment: What version of IE? Because IE8 and below does not support HTML5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using the `<video>` tag in `html5' is good practice to:

- Include width and height attributes, to avoid that the video will flicker while loading.
- Not every browser is able to use a specific format, so you need to add other formats too.
- It is also usefull to put some text which will display if the browser is not capable to use the `video' tag.

> ```
>      <h2>Video from last year</h2>
>         <video width="320" height="240" controls>
>           <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
>           <source src="my_video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
>           <source src="my_video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
>           We are sorry but your browser does not support the video tag.
>         </video>
>     </section>
> ```

You can also if you wish display an image as placeholder normally called 'poster'

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls poster="poster_image.png">
```

**Old browsers do not support the `video' tag at all.**